# How to include angular2/4 component in JSP page?

Tags: angular, jsp

I want to add angular component into JSP page, what are the possible ways ?

To Describe more :

I have one application dynamic web application in JSP and another I created is an angular component which does some authentication.
Is there way to use this component in JSP web application, apart from object,embedd or iframe ?

Comment: You can only include an Angular application, not a component.

Comment: Kindly provide a detailed view on what you have tried, where you are stuck and try to pin point exactly where you are stuck.

Comment: I doubt it is a good idea. JSP are server side generated pages whereas angular is a client-side framework. Angular works well with restful backend services.

Comment: like I create my own <authenticate-component></authenticate-component> in angular2 and then want this component to be invoked by jsp application.
I tried with <object> as well as <embedd> tags to include my hosted angular component application, but when I try to access google or any other application it give below error

"in a 'https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2.....  frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'sameorigin'."

@ Günter Zöchbauer, @Raghav,

Tried to include it as an application

Comment: It's no different than adding to an HTML file.

Comment: @nitind How should I achieve it ?

Answer (score 2):

I am able to include my angular component into jsp by bootstrapping it into my application and it runs fine.
Below is one way of doing so. Another you can also include the whole component code and bootstrap angular module.

1. Include below scripts into your index.jsp. here ***my-app*** is name of my component

> ```
>     <script src="node_modules/@angular/common/common.umd.js"></script>
>     <script src="node_modules/@angular/compiler/compiler.umd.js"></script>
>     <script src="node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js"></script>
>     <script src="node_modules/reflect-metadata/Reflect.js"></script>
>     <script src="node_modules/rxjs/bundles/Rx.umd.js"></script>
>     <script src="node_modules/@angular/core/core.umd.js"></script>
>     <script src="node_modules/@angular/platform-browser/platform-browser.umd.js"></script>
>     <script src="node_modules/@angular/platform-browser-dynamic/platform-browser-dynamic.umd.js"></script>
>
>     <!-- Our app -->
>     <script src="app.js"></script> 
>   <body>
>   <my-app></my-app>
>   <body>
> ```

2. Create app.js file which will bootstrap your angular component.

app.js

> ```
> (function() {
>   var MyApp = ng.core.Component({
>       selector : 'my-app',
>       template : '<h1>Hello Angular 2!</h1>'
>   }).Class({
>       constructor : function() {
>       }
>   });
>
>   document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
>       ng.platformBrowserDynamic.bootstrap(MyApp);
>   });
>
> })();
> ```

For more information you can read bootstrapping angular application.

Answer (score 1):

Another way I was able to do it, by building the angular component with command:

```
ng build
```

This will generate JavaScript files will be created in dist folder of your angular project.

Then just include the files from the dist folder into your JSP application and use angular component directly.

Comment: Does this work on IE 11? Works fine with Chrome and Firefox.

Comment: Hello Amit 
If your angular project works on IE11, it will work on it as well, in my case it worked

Comment: How did you include the index.html from your jsp? In my case I did it as <%@include  file="angular-files/dist/index.html" %> but it doesn't work.

Comment: If you see your angular app index.html,
there you will find your component's tag.
For example 
<app-root></app-root>
or your custom name which you have specified in "selector".

You just need to copy the content of angular's index.html into your jsp page and update <base href="/"> to respect to your folder structure.


There is no need for <%@include file="angular-files/dist/index.html" %>

Comment: @SukhmeetSinghKhokhar Your files in the dist are they hashed ? If yes, how can you dynamically add hashed files to your jsp? Thx

Answer (score 0):

One can use `ng build -bh <WebAppContextPath>` from the location of your angular project.
For instance, if you have named your project as client (generated using `ng new client`) it will create a dist folder under the project client.

Copy the contents from the dist folder to your WebApp in the WebContent folder.
Now either use the index.html of your client project or paste it to the index.jsp. Now access the webApp, now angular 2 components will be served.

Please note that when the build in for non-production, all the `node_modules` will served from the location of client project, if you want to server everything from the webApp itself then build it for prod mode `ng build -bh <WebAppContext> --prod`, all modules will be combined into single file.

Answer (score 0):

I was recently working on the similar use case where I had to add the angular page on to the JSP page. 
Based on what I did, this is what you can also do:
You can copy and add all  and  tags to your JSP page from the index.html file that is contained in the build directory of your angular application. 
In case that your build of the angular application is with --prod option, since the file under your build directory(normally 'dist'), is named with the dynamic hash (this is named this way for cache busting purpose), you need to create a logic which loops over files in the dist folder and find the CSS and js files dynamically based on the extensions of each file and create the corresponding string literal with  or  based on files type(.js or .css). After this, you need to include those string literals in the JSP file using **out.print()** statement.

Then finally you can add your angular component selector like  on your JSP page. As you have all the required scripts and CSS already added, it should work without any issues.