# how do you create a war for spring boot / react application

Tags: reactjs, spring, spring-boot

I have a spring boot app as backend and using react as front end (both are in same project).  I only have the one pom file for the backend and I run the spring app manually and then do a npm start on the frontend, all works fine.  What I want to do now is deploy both backend and frontend and start them up automatically.  Do I need another POM file for the front end or something which will execute npm etc?  Front end was created with create-react-app and currently running on port 3000 ( "start": "react-scripts start" ), my backend running on port 8080 but would be deployed to an external tomcat server.

Do I need to add the following plugin:

```
 <groupId>com.github.eirslett</groupId>
 <artifactId>frontend-maven-plugin</artifactId>
```

and then some execution rules in the pom?

Any information is much appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If you want to create war in spring boot, you need to add `packaging` as war and `spring-boot-starter-tomcat` should be `<scope>provided</scope>`. I think yes you need to add, please check the reference in the below url,

https://github.com/spring-guides/tut-react-and-spring-data-rest/blob/master/basic/pom.xml

Ref: https://spring.io/guides/tutorials/react-and-spring-data-rest/

```
        <packaging>war</packaging>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
```

Comment: I have got my Spring Boot app running with React having added the frontend-maven-plugin to my pom file, but I also had to use a groupId of com.greglturnquist in my parent element section of my pom file, why is this?  Thanks

Comment: Is this a parent pom provided by Spring which does all the npm install etc?

Comment: This plugin downloads and installs Node and NPM locally, and runs npm install.

Answer (score 0):

let me chip in and say something else. If you need a war as packaging, you can proceed as per Thangavel said. But I am a bit sceptical to go for a deployment like that on a production site.

Since you are using a front-end framework and spring as backend, I would suggest another way. Usually after doing a build of your front-end, you will use a http server like apache or nginx to deploy your build and then your war or jar for your spring boot project.

But if you want to keep both in the same project, you can do a build of your react project and it should be possible to import those JS files of your build in a thymeleaf or JSP view. Then you would only need to run the project on port 8080.

Here is an example for Angular. I am sure you can look for same in React.

[How to include angular2/4 component in JSP page?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45282825/how-to-include-angular2-4-component-in-jsp-page)

Please let me know how it goes.

Comment: Hi, thanks for this, I wasn't sure you could add React to a thymeleaf view.

Answer (score 0):

If you want a good reference implementation you can generate a [jhipster](https://www.jhipster.tech/) project and look at how the frontend plugin is used.

Comment: Thanks for this, will take a look at that.